# Why does twig render error twice under checkbox

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, symfony, bootstrap-4, twig

My custom theme for `bootstrap_4_layout` looks like this:

```
{% extends "bootstrap_4_layout.html.twig" %}

{# this is basically the default form_label block, but with the form_error block definition removed, see line 260 of bootstrap_4_layout.html.twig #}
{% block form_label -%}
    {# I think you can safely remove this if-statement, you currently might end up with 2 errors when you have a form with no label defined. #}
    {% if label is not same as(false) -%}
        {%- if compound is defined and compound -%}
            {%- set element = 'legend' -%}
            {%- set label_attr = label_attr|merge({class: (label_attr.class|default('') ~ ' col-form-label')|trim}) -%}
        {%- else -%}
            {%- set label_attr = label_attr|merge({for: id}) -%}
        {%- endif -%}
        {% if required -%}
            {% set label_attr = label_attr|merge({class: (label_attr.class|default('') ~ ' required')|trim}) %}
        {%- endif -%}
        {% if label is empty -%}
            {%- if label_format is not empty -%}
                {% set label = label_format|replace({
                    '%name%': name,
                    '%id%': id,
                }) %}
            {%- else -%}
                {% set label = name|humanize %}
            {%- endif -%}
        {%- endif -%}
        <{{ element|default('label') }}{% if label_attr %}{% with { attr: label_attr } %}{{ block('attributes') }}{% endwith %}{% endif %}>
        {%- if translation_domain is same as(false) -%}
            {%- if label_html is same as(false) -%}
                {{- label -}}
            {%- else -%}
                {{- label|raw -}}
            {%- endif -%}
        {%- else -%}
            {%- if label_html is same as(false) -%}
                {{- label|trans(label_translation_parameters, translation_domain) -}}
            {%- else -%}
                {{- label|trans(label_translation_parameters, translation_domain)|raw -}}
            {%- endif -%}
        {%- endif -%}
        {# here was the form_errors call which is now gone #}</{{ element|default('label') }}>
    {%- else -%}
        {%- if errors|length > 0 -%}
        <div id="{{ id }}_errors" class="mb-2">
            {{- form_errors(form) -}}
        </div>
        {%- endif -%}
    {%- endif -%}
{%- endblock form_label %}

{# here, we're adding the form_errors(form) call we just removed from the form_label block, so the error is in the correct position #}
{% block form_row -%}
    {%- if compound is defined and compound -%}
        {%- set element = 'fieldset' -%}
    {%- endif -%}
    {%- set widget_attr = {} -%}
    {%- if help is not empty -%}
        {%- set widget_attr = {attr: {'aria-describedby': id ~"_help"}} -%}
    {%- endif -%}
    <{{ element|default('div') }}{% with {attr: row_attr|merge({class: (row_attr.class|default('') ~ ' form-group')|trim})} %}{{ block('attributes') }}{% endwith %}>
        {{- form_label(form) -}}
        {{- form_widget(form, widget_attr) -}}
        {{- form_help(form) -}}
        {{- form_errors(form) -}} {# << here :-) #}
    </{{ element|default('div') }}>
{%- endblock form_row %}
```

Generally, this code renders the error-tag under input, default is above.

Every error is rendered fine, but on checkbox, it is rendered twice:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ld0M2.png)

Comment: checkboxes / radiobuttons are always a bit weird, since it's usually not "label [break] input" but "input label" (all wrapped in a `<label>`). however, the label is probably not rendered via form_label, but form_input, but the error might be rendered in both. anyway, you probably have to check the final templates for widget/label/row of those element.

Comment: Hmm, I still dont know how to repair it.